# Need info to run hapi and inert with node.js on Win XP

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

Is there some documentation for hapi and inert running on node 0.12 since it has to be on win xp? Which versions do I need?

Answer (score 0):

Was to tired to recognize that version can be selected from doc pages! :(